# how to detect gif in telegram bot python

Tags: python-3.x, handler, gif, content-type, telegram-bot

everyone. I don´t know how to detect gifs with my bot in telegram. The following example is when bot detect text on the chat and the text is "hi" the bot reply "Hi".

I think that I can do something with content_type but I dont know.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    if message.text == 'hi' :
        cid= message.chat.id
        bot.send_message(cid, 'Hi')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect GIFs you have to use the [document filter](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.document) in your [message handler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html).

This will run the provided function on every message that contains a document. But please note that documents can be more than just GIFs. This is from the documentation:

> This object represents a general file (as opposed to photos, voice
>   messages and audio files).

Regular files (for example a `.zip` archive) are treated as a document too. In order to identify a GIF you need to look for the `mime_type` of the document. Here is an example code:

```
def docmsg(bot, update):
   if message.document.mime_type == "video/mp4":
      print("This is a GIF!")

dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document, docmsg))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Since videos are not treated as documents, regular `video/mp4` will not be caught here. However, telegram uses the MP4 format for all GIFs, so this is a failsafe way to detect GIFs.

Comment: Please be aware that in your first answer it will not only detect GIFs. Other `document` type files like `PDF` files for example will also be detected.

Comment: content_types=['document', 'gif']

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py

lane 1336 :)

Comment: this afternoon i will check if detect PDF don´t worry

Comment: Thats perfect, i prove it now , thank you and sorry for last comments :D very good man!